# Output parameter value is shown as 'invalid identifier'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to retrieve values from temporarily created tables. But the return value throws the error 'Invalid Identifier'

```
create or replace procedure edu_stream (input in varchar2,vals out varchar2)
    as
    inp varchar2(30);
    valu varchar2(30);
    begin
    inp:=input;
    if inp='secondary education' then

         Execute immediate'WITH secedu as (
    (SELECT "ICSE" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "CBSE" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "STATE BOARD" as name FROM dual)
    )        
    SELECT name into valu from(SELECT name
        FROM  secedu ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)where rownum<2';

        vals:=valu;

    else 
    if inp='intermediate education' then

      Execute immediate'WITH intedu as (
    (SELECT "MPC" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "BIPC" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "MBIPC" as name FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT "CEC" as name FROM dual)
    )        
    SELECT name into valu from(SELECT name
        FROM intedu ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)where rownum<2'; 

        vals:=valu;

        else 
    if inp='Graduation' then

      Execute immediate'WITH gedu as (
    (SELECT "ECE" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "CSE" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "CE" as name FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT "EEE" as name FROM dual)UNION
    (SELECT "ME" as name FROM dual)UNION
    (SELECT "AE" as name FROM dual)UNION
    (SELECT "BIOTECH" as name FROM dual)UNION
    (SELECT "EIE" as name FROM dual)
    )       
    SELECT name into valu from(SELECT name
        FROM gedu ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)where rownum<2'; 

        vals:=valu;


        else 
    if inp='post-graduation' then

      Execute immediate'WITH pgedu as (
    (SELECT "MCA" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "MTECH" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "MSC" as name FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT "MBA" as name FROM dual)
    )        
    SELECT name into valu from(SELECT name
        FROM pgedu ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)where rownum<2'; 

        vals:=valu;

       else 
    if inp='phd'then

     Execute immediate' WITH phdedu as (
    (SELECT "Doctorate of philosophy" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "doctorate of medicine" as name FROM dual ) UNION
    (SELECT "doctorate of science" as name FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT "Doctorate of computer sciences" as name FROM dual)
    )        
    SELECT name into valu from(SELECT name
        FROM phdgedu ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)where rownum<2'; 

        vals:=valu;
    end if;
    end if;
    end if;
    end if;
    end if;
    end;
```

Execution:

```
declare 
value1 varchar2(30);
cv varchar2(30);
begin
cv:='secondary education';
edu_stream(cv,value1);
dbms_output.put_line('val is'||value1);
end;
```

Error report:

> Error starting at line 2 in command: declare  value1 varchar2(30); cv
>   varchar2(30); begin cv:='secondary education'; edu_stream(cv,value1);
>   dbms_output.put_line('val is'||value1); end; Error report: ORA-00904:
>   "ICSE": invalid identifier ORA-06512: at "DATAFOCUS_GROUP.EDU_STREAM",
>   line 9 ORA-06512: at line 6
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

if I use 'ICSE'instead of "ICSE"

ERROR SHOWS-

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ICSE" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>   ERROR     103   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
>   return
>   returning  <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
>   like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
>   member submultiset

Comment: There is no `ICSE` column on `DUAL` table.

Comment: you probably want `'ICSE'` instead of `"ICSE"`, same for the other varchar values. Varchar values have to have a sorrounding `''` and not a `""`. Additionally you can do `execute immediate('query') into vals.`.

Comment: yes, i did try the other way- using 'ICSE'. But the error is showing as above

Comment: @EmilySharon make it `''ICSE''` in the varchar to surround it with a `'`.

Comment: Also, why all those execute immediate? You seem not to need dynamic sql, so try to simplify your code avoiding dynamic sql

Comment: Well I just tried, ' 'ICSE' '. But the error says 'missing keyword'

Comment: "but the error says ..."  - it is a DIFFERENT error, you have too many in your code. After you fix one, you will get a different error, that is absolutely normal (and in fact it shows progress). Don't expect the fix to one error to fix ALL your errors!

Comment: What's the point of the variable `inp` in your code? You simply assign to it the value of the input variable `input`. Why don't you just use `input` directly - why do you need to create a separate variable in the function?

Comment: And why so many levels of nested if's when in fact they are all at the same level? Use IF -> THEN -> ELSIF -> ...

Comment: I had an error previously which made me think that parameters do not accept values directly. But what you've said is right!

Comment: Ok Mathguy Thank you.

Comment: This site works best when you ask a really specific question, rather than dumping 80 lines of code and saying it doesn't compile.

Comment: Try to make of your code a more readable layout. Not only for us (who want to help you), but certain for your self.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid dynamic SQL; also, probably due to confusion created by dynamic sql, you are using `"` instead of `'`.
You can re-write your code as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE edu_stream(input IN VARCHAR2, vals OUT VARCHAR2) AS
    inp                                     VARCHAR2(30);
    valu                                    VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    inp    := input;

    IF inp = 'secondary education'
    THEN
        WITH secedu AS
                 ((SELECT 'ICSE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                  UNION
                  (SELECT 'CBSE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                  UNION
                  (SELECT 'STATE BOARD' AS name FROM DUAL))
        SELECT name
          INTO valu
          FROM (  SELECT name
                    FROM secedu
                ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
         WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

        vals    := valu;
    ELSE
        IF inp = 'intermediate education'
        THEN
            WITH intedu AS
                     ((SELECT 'MPC' AS name FROM DUAL)
                      UNION
                      (SELECT 'BIPC' AS name FROM DUAL)
                      UNION
                      (SELECT 'MBIPC' AS name FROM DUAL)
                      UNION
                      (SELECT 'CEC' AS name FROM DUAL))
            SELECT name
              INTO valu
              FROM (  SELECT name
                        FROM intedu
                    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
             WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

            vals    := valu;
        ELSE
            IF inp = 'Graduation'
            THEN
                WITH gedu AS
                         ((SELECT 'ECE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'CSE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'CE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'EEE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'ME' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'AE' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'BIOTECH' AS name FROM DUAL)
                          UNION
                          (SELECT 'EIE' AS name FROM DUAL))
                SELECT name
                  INTO valu
                  FROM (  SELECT name
                            FROM gedu
                        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
                 WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

                vals    := valu;
            ELSE
                IF inp = 'post-graduation'
                THEN
                    WITH pgedu AS
                             ((SELECT 'MCA' AS name FROM DUAL)
                              UNION
                              (SELECT 'MTECH' AS name FROM DUAL)
                              UNION
                              (SELECT 'MSC' AS name FROM DUAL)
                              UNION
                              (SELECT 'MBA' AS name FROM DUAL))
                    SELECT name
                      INTO valu
                      FROM (  SELECT name
                                FROM pgedu
                            ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
                     WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

                    vals    := valu;
                ELSE
                    IF inp = 'phd'
                    THEN
                        WITH phdedu AS
                                 ((SELECT 'Doctorate of philosophy' AS name FROM DUAL)
                                  UNION
                                  (SELECT 'doctorate of medicine' AS name FROM DUAL)
                                  UNION
                                  (SELECT 'doctorate of science' AS name FROM DUAL)
                                  UNION
                                  (SELECT 'Doctorate of computer sciences' AS name FROM DUAL))
                        SELECT name
                          INTO valu
                          FROM (  SELECT name
                                    FROM phdgedu
                                ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
                         WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

                        vals    := valu;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Also, please notice that the variables `inp` and `valu` are not strictly necessary: you can simply use the parameters to check the input value and build the output parameter.

In case you need do use dynamic SQL (not here, but maybe in the future) the right way is something like:

```
declare
    a number;
begin
    execute immediate 'select 1 from dual' into a;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer sticking with your dynamic SQL.

personal preference: i´d allways end a line with `' ||`, to make it clear you are not missing a whitespace (even though it should just execute fine).

remove the `into valu` from the dynamic sql and make it a `execute immediate 'query' into vals` clause.

As an example i´m just using your first query:

```
Execute immediate 'WITH secedu as ( ' ||
   '(SELECT ''ICSE'' as name FROM dual ) UNION ' ||
   '(SELECT ''CBSE'' as name FROM dual ) UNION ' ||
   '(SELECT ''STATE'' BOARD" as name FROM dual) ' ||
   ')         ' ||
'SELECT name from(SELECT name ' ||
    'FROM  secedu ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)where rownum<2'
into vals;
```

Comment: Okay Thank you Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

You might have your own learning objectives but when those put aside the code is simply awful and unnecessary complex PL/SQL. Here is a partial but completely functional rewrite with references to relevant Oracle PL/SQL documentation. Hope you'll find the presented ideas useful !

```
-- blocks: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/overview.htm#LNPLS141
declare
  -- nested tables: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99981
  type str_list_t is table of varchar2(32767);
  -- subprograms: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS008
  -- common parts of f() refactored to r()
  function r(p_list in str_list_t) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return p_list(floor(dbms_random.value(1, p_list.count + 1)));
  end;
  function f(p_edu_level in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return
      -- simple case: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS394
      case p_edu_level
        when 'secondary' then r(str_list_t('ICSE', 'CBSE', 'STATE BOARD'))
        when 'intermediate' then r(str_list_t('MPC', 'BIPC', 'MIPC', 'CEC'))
        -- add here your other education levels, you should see the pattern ...
        else null
      end;
  end;
begin
  -- for loop: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS411
  for i in 1 .. 10
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('secondary: ' || f('secondary'));
    dbms_output.put_line('intermediate: ' || f('intermediate'));
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('batman: ' || f('batman'));
end;
/
```